# Select first-child in nested div

Tags: css

I have the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" required="required" type="text" name="order[name]" id="order_name" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" required="required" type="text" name="order[email]" id="order_email" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" required="required" type="text" name="order[age]" id="order_age" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" required="required" type="text" name="order[address]" id="order_address" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On every `.row`, I wanna select the first `.form-control`. I tried `.row .form-control:first-child` but it selects all `.form-control`. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Are there other rows that DO NOT contain `.form-control`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because it is searching for the first occurrence of `form-control` within a parent group. You just need to adjust your selector to take the first occurrence of the child `<div>` in `.row`.

I could see a potential issue with this selector, however, if the first child `<div>` is not the one that contains a `.form-control`, but I don't know the full extent of your markup, so this could work just fine.

```css
.row > div:first-child .form-control {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" required="required" type="text" name="order[name]" id="order_name" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" required="required" type="text" name="order[email]" id="order_email" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" required="required" type="text" name="order[age]" id="order_age" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" required="required" type="text" name="order[address]" id="order_address" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `:first-child` and `:first-of-type` selectors work with respect to a parent element. In your selector the children are being searched in `.row`. So when it reaches `.row` it goes to `col-xs-4` and `col-xs-8` the parents it searches in reference to are these `col-xs`'s now. So it see's a `.form-control` in both and in both the cases the `.form-control`'s are the firs children so it selects both of them in both the `.row`'s.

If you're using the same structure you can do this:

```
.row .col-xs-4 .form-control {
    background-color:red;
}
```

In this case the `.col-xs-4` always comes first so it looks for the `.form-control` only in the first column.

Now let say you had a different markup and instead of `.col-xs-4` and `.col-xs-8` you had two `.col-xs-4`'s. in that case you could do this:

```
.row .col-xs-4:first-of-type .form-control {
    background-color:red;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mfvs2sc/  [different columns]
          http://jsfiddle.net/rmggct9v/  [same columns]

Hope that helps!